# Geolocation classic asp json response

Tags: json, asp-classic, geolocation

I'm trying to parse an json response from google maps geolocation api. I'm getting an json response with this code:

```
     set xmlHTTP = server.createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
     xmlHTTP.open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=50.9255685,29.2703104&destinations=46.446251,28.570993&mode=driving&language=sv-SE&sensor=false", false
     xmlHTTP.send()
     LatLongFeed = xmlHTTP.ResponseText
```

I have tried to get the values for street adress (origin and destination and i have tried to get distance but i cant get it to work.

How do i get the values in the response so i can use it in my classic asp code?

Comment: It would help if you would show us what you have tried and where/how it is failing.

Comment: I tried the googleapis url and some of the json response used Cyrillic (ie Russian) letters. Is your asp page set up to cope with that?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried different kind of solutions and this is based on an JSON class (http://www.aspjson.com/)

```
Set oJSON = New aspJSON

'Load JSON string
oJSON.loadJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" & rs("LatiStart")& "," & rs("LongStart")& "&destinations=" & rs("LatiStop")& "," & rs("LongStop")& "&mode=driving&language=sv-SE&sensor=false")

'Get single value
Response.Write oJSON.data("distance") & "<br>"

'Loop through collection
For Each subItem In oJSON.data("distance")
    Response.Write subItem & ": " & _
    oJSON.data("distance").item(subItem) & "<br>"
Next

'Return the object
Response.Write oJSON.JSONoutput()
```

When running this i get 
LineNumber 55 
ErrorCode 800a01c3 
Description Object not a collection

Line 55 is (For Each subItem In oJSON.data("distance"))

The json response in my example is based on example coordinates and is'nt the actual location. The adresses is only containing standard a-z.

Comment: This should be an edit of the question as it is not an answer.  P.S.   
From release Release 1.13 December 2013 of ASPJSON you can actually load the JSON directly with the URL as you tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

The load JSON does not work that way. You should load the response of your call to googleapis in there, not the request URL.
So something like this:

```
URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" & rs("LatiStart")& "," & rs("LongStart")& "&destinations=" & rs("LatiStop")& "," & rs("LongStop")& "&mode=driving&language=sv-SE&sensor=false"
Set objXmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
objXmlHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

objXmlHttp.Send
Set oJSON = New aspJSON
oJSON.loadJSON(objXmlHTTP.ResponseText)
```

Comment: From release Release 1.13 December 2013 of ASPJSON you can actually load the JSON directly with the URL.